# Lost & Found - BRICK

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

This could be an interesting Question.

I Found and iPhone 5S, I handed it into the police. After 2 Months they returned the Phone, no one claimed it. I have a Sticker on the back of the phone with police details on it.
So in our country, that is proof of ownership. I am now the new owner of this phone.
BUT.....It is a brick, as the security has been enabled.
I have a start up screen that looks like a brand new phone and I must enter an iCloud account and password.
I do not have this information.
I have contacted Apple Help USA, They say I need a court summons ??? WHAT!!!
I contacted Apple technical Support, ( basically they said NO )
SO. the Question is....
Is there a way around this? 
( I am happy to send a photo with the police details on it. To prove ownership.)
Thanks 
Anthony

Comment: When I found the Phone, it was in a baseball jacket inside out. I found the phone in it. I left the jacket on the tree, and I was going to come back with a note to say. If you have lost your phone, call it and I will give you my address. But when I charged the phone, the screen cover had a gang insignia ( Like a motorcycle patch ).
   I thought that the police would be interested in this. They were very interested. They said that Burglars that have been working in the area flip their jackets inside out to put the dogs off there sent

Comment: Initially, the phone had a Standard Lock Screen. The phone was not reported lost and was on pre-paid. ( cannot be tracked )
The Previous owner does not want to be linked to the jacket.
Police tried to unlock, extra security was instigated.
SO I OWN A BRICK - THAT IS GOOD FOR PARTS

Comment: This is also personal. 
I had my house robbed some time ago. they took $25,000 Dollars worth of gear and also stole my hand built Red Convertable. http://www.aipdesignz.com/projects/20985631/
  So I was happy to give this phone to the police, so they maybe could catch these bastards. But in doing so, it has also turned this phone into an untraceable brick. The iPhone security is good for personal information for legitimate users, but this also benefits the criminal fraternity.

Comment: Link to Photos of Phone.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0V4HFVk4XbSYk5lNlh5VnlxNFk

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunate that the original owner could not be found.

Apple has deliberately designed the device to be linked to an individual. Without that individual's involvement, the security will not be bypassed by Apple without a court order.

Consider returning the phone to Apple for [parts recycling](https://www.apple.com/nz/recycling/):

> #### Recycling an Apple product should be as easy as using one.
>
> The Apple Renew program lets you recycle your device online. We’ll make sure it’s recycled responsibly or given a chance to be used again.

Comment: Thanks, Graham. 
I thought that would be the answer. 
My provider Vodafone are offering a deal if you trade an iPhone, they will give you $300 Dollars off a new iPhone 6. 
They take the phone and on sell them. They are refurbished and sold on.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I have just read the conditions of their deal...NO.... BACK TO BEING A BRICK AGAIN.

Comment: " On Account open term plan – only available when you trade in an iPhone 4 or higher model. It must be in full working condition. We accept Trade-Ins where the screen is broken, the iPhone just needs to be able to be powered on, make a call and send a TXT. Find my iPhone must be turned off and the phone unlocked."